# What is Project Ara?

Tags: android, mobile

I have difficulty understanding Project Ara. Can we build our own functional smartphone using it? Wiki describes it as "Project Ara is the codename for an initiative by Google that aims to develop a free, open hardware platform for creating highly modular smartphones".
And the MDK contains only CAD files.How do we add our own modules into it?

Comment: StackOverflow is for software programming questions, not hardware manufacturing questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your hardware if you have your knowledge. It is more likely a whitebox computer.

"Project Ara phone is a "white box" computer"

http://projectaratalk.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5